# Choosing database type between NoSql (Cassandra or MongoDb) and SQL for big e-commerce project including long text search on unstructured data models

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, cassandra

**We are developing an e-commerce platform where clients can search products from all types like house, transport, clothing etc. So we are struggling to choose database system NoSQL or SQL because of its unstructured object models.**

> I am considering to pick NoSQL Mongo DB because it supports unstructured data but I am not sure how full-text search works. Besides I have no idea how to save and retrieve unstructured data
>
> My Colleague is suggesting to use SQL with multiple tables for each data model and create one big lucene data table for full-text search purposes.

---

> My question what would you recommend. I have no prior experience in MongoDB or cassandra. However I have been involved a bit in projects in which MongoDB is implemented. I am considering one way to save objects which is as JSON string format and parse according to its type after I retrieve the object from database.

Comment: This article has some useful info:  [MongoDB vs MySQL](https://www.mongodb.com/compare/mongodb-mysql).

Comment: Store unstructured data in monogodb as you say. Use Elasticsearch noSQL on top of mongo to power your search. I found one article on medium to give you an overview. you can have a look : https://medium.com/@xoor/indexing-mongodb-with-elasticsearch-2c428b676343

Comment: Thank you guys for such quick responses. I have decided to go with MongoDB with Elastic Search (using mongo-connector) so I hope I will have something interesting by the end of this week. thanks a lot :)